# No type named 'VideoCapture' in namespace 'cv'

Tags: c++, openframeworks

hi i'm a beginner trying to learn openFrameworks and I get this error when I run my code. I've been looking around and cannot find a solution, please help. It is running on xcode and I have managed to run previous apps before.

ofApp.h

```
    #pragma once
#include "ofMain.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp {

public:
    void setup();
    void update();
    void draw();

    void keyPressed(int key) {};
    void keyReleased(int key) {};
    void mouseMoved(int x, int y) {};
    void mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button) {};
    void mousePressed(int x, int y, int button) {};
    void mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button) {};
    void windowResized(int w, int h) {};
    void dragEvent(ofDragInfo dragInfo) {};
    void gotMessage(ofMessage msg) {};

    ofEasyCam cam;

    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cv::Size cap_size;
    int number_of_frames;
    vector<cv::Mat> frame_list;

    ofImage image;
    cv::Mat frame;
    vector<ofMesh> mesh_list;
};
```

ofApp.cpp

```
    #include "ofApp.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::setup() {

    ofSetFrameRate(60);
    ofSetWindowTitle("openFrameworks");

    ofBackground(239);
    ofSetColor(255);
    ofEnableDepthTest();

    this->cap.open("D:\\video\\image51.mp4");
    this->cap_size = cv::Size(256, 144);

    this->image.allocate(this->cap_size.width, this->cap_size.height, OF_IMAGE_COLOR);
    this->frame = cv::Mat(cv::Size(this->image.getWidth(), this->image.getHeight()), CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8UC3, this->image.getPixels().getNumChannels()), this->image.getPixels().getData(), 0);

    this->number_of_frames = 25 * 27;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->number_of_frames; i++) {

        cv::Mat src, tmp;
        this->cap >> src;
        if (src.empty()) {

            return;
        }

        cv::resize(src, tmp, this->cap_size);
        cv::cvtColor(tmp, tmp, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);

        this->frame_list.push_back(tmp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {

        ofMesh mesh;
        mesh.addVertex(glm::vec3(-128, -72, 0));
        mesh.addVertex(glm::vec3(128, -72, 0));
        mesh.addVertex(glm::vec3(128, 72, 0));
        mesh.addVertex(glm::vec3(-128, 72, 0));

        mesh.addTexCoord(glm::vec3(0, 0, 0));
        mesh.addTexCoord(glm::vec3(256, 0, 0));
        mesh.addTexCoord(glm::vec3(256, 144, 0));
        mesh.addTexCoord(glm::vec3(0, 144, 0));

        mesh.addIndex(0); mesh.addIndex(1); mesh.addIndex(2);
        mesh.addIndex(0); mesh.addIndex(2); mesh.addIndex(3);

        this->mesh_list.push_back(mesh);
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::update() {

    ofSeedRandom(39);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::draw() {

    this->cam.begin();
    ofRotateX(180);
    ofRotateY(ofGetFrameNum() * 0.5);

    for (auto& mesh : this->mesh_list) {

        auto location = glm::vec3(ofRandom(-500, 500), ofRandom(-500, 500), ofRandom(-500, 500));
        //int n = ofMap(ofNoise(glm::vec4(location, ofGetFrameNum() * 0.005)), 0, 1, 0, this->number_of_frames);
        int n = int(ofRandom(1000) + ofGetFrameNum()) % this->number_of_frames;
        this->frame_list[n].copyTo(this->frame);
        this->image.update();

        ofPushMatrix();
        ofTranslate(location);

        this->image.bind();
        mesh.draw();
        this->image.unbind();

        ofPopMatrix();
    }

    this->cam.end();
}
```

main.cpp

```
   #include "ofApp.cpp"
#include "ofApp.h"

//========================================================================
int main() {

    ofSetupOpenGL(1280, 720, OF_WINDOW);
    ofRunApp(new ofApp());
}
```

I get 2 errors: "No matching function for call to 'ofRunApp'" and "No type named 'VideoCapture' in namespace 'cv'"

I have sourced the code from https://github.com/junkiyoshi/Insta20200217 as I am trying to learn and develop an art project similar to this. Any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please add `#include "highgui.h"` to your main.cpp

Comment: I have tried this and still comes up with the same errors: "No type named 'VideoCapture' in namespace 'cv'" and "No matching function for call to 'ofRunApp'"

Comment: Thanks. In that case, include highgui.h. I've updated my answer

Comment: I tried this out and it now says "lexical or preprocessor issue" "'highgui.h file not found"